# Select box options not showing on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a strange problem where the select box options are not showing up on iPhones. When you click the select box the screen flickers but does not show any options. Any ideas ?

You can see it in action here :  http://demo.elusivethemes.com/affliction/product/blue-fire-shirt/

Ive figured out its the stickysidebar thats causing the issue. Is there anyway to modify this so it only runs on screensizes over a certain width ?

```
// Sticky Sidebar

(function() {
  var $, win;

  $ = this.jQuery || window.jQuery;

  win = $(window);

 $.fn.stick_in_parent = function(opts) {
var doc, elm, enable_bottoming, fn, i, inner_scrolling, len, manual_spacer, offset_top, parent_selector, recalc_every, sticky_class;
if (opts == null) {
  opts = {};
}
sticky_class = opts.sticky_class, inner_scrolling = opts.inner_scrolling, recalc_every = opts.recalc_every, parent_selector = opts.parent, offset_top = opts.offset_top, manual_spacer = opts.spacer, enable_bottoming = opts.bottoming;
if (offset_top == null) {
  offset_top = 0;
}
if (parent_selector == null) {
  parent_selector = void 0;
}
if (inner_scrolling == null) {
  inner_scrolling = true;
}
if (sticky_class == null) {
  sticky_class = "is_stuck";
}
doc = $(document);
if (enable_bottoming == null) {
  enable_bottoming = true;
}
fn = function(elm, padding_bottom, parent_top, parent_height, top, height, el_float, detached) {
  var bottomed, detach, fixed, last_pos, last_scroll_height, offset, parent, recalc, recalc_and_tick, recalc_counter, spacer, tick;
  if (elm.data("sticky_kit")) {
    return;
  }
  elm.data("sticky_kit", true);
  last_scroll_height = doc.height();
  parent = elm.parent();
  if (parent_selector != null) {
    parent = parent.closest(parent_selector);
  }
  if (!parent.length) {
    throw "failed to find stick parent";
  }
  fixed = false;
  bottomed = false;
  spacer = manual_spacer != null ? manual_spacer && elm.closest(manual_spacer) : $("<div />");
  if (spacer) {
    spacer.css('position', elm.css('position'));
  }
  recalc = function() {
    var border_top, padding_top, restore;
    if (detached) {
      return;
    }
    last_scroll_height = doc.height();
    border_top = parseInt(parent.css("border-top-width"), 10);
    padding_top = parseInt(parent.css("padding-top"), 10);
    padding_bottom = parseInt(parent.css("padding-bottom"), 10);
    parent_top = parent.offset().top + border_top + padding_top;
    parent_height = parent.height();
    if (fixed) {
      fixed = false;
      bottomed = false;
      if (manual_spacer == null) {
        elm.insertAfter(spacer);
        spacer.detach();
      }
      elm.css({
        position: "",
        top: "",
        width: "",
        bottom: ""
      }).removeClass(sticky_class);
      restore = true;
    }
    top = elm.offset().top - (parseInt(elm.css("margin-top"), 10) || 0) - offset_top;
    height = elm.outerHeight(true);
    el_float = elm.css("float");
    if (spacer) {
      spacer.css({
        width: elm.outerWidth(true),
        height: height,
        display: elm.css("display"),
        "vertical-align": elm.css("vertical-align"),
        "float": el_float
      });
    }
    if (restore) {
      return tick();
    }
  };
  recalc();
  if (height === parent_height) {
    return;
  }
  last_pos = void 0;
  offset = offset_top;
  recalc_counter = recalc_every;
  tick = function() {
    var css, delta, recalced, scroll, will_bottom, win_height;
    if (detached) {
      return;
    }
    recalced = false;
    if (recalc_counter != null) {
      recalc_counter -= 1;
      if (recalc_counter <= 0) {
        recalc_counter = recalc_every;
        recalc();
        recalced = true;
      }
    }
    if (!recalced && doc.height() !== last_scroll_height) {
      recalc();
      recalced = true;
    }
    scroll = win.scrollTop();
    if (last_pos != null) {
      delta = scroll - last_pos;
    }
    last_pos = scroll;
    if (fixed) {
      if (enable_bottoming) {
        will_bottom = scroll + height + offset > parent_height + parent_top;
        if (bottomed && !will_bottom) {
          bottomed = false;
          elm.css({
            position: "fixed",
            bottom: "",
            top: offset
          }).trigger("sticky_kit:unbottom");
        }
      }
      if (scroll < top) {
        fixed = false;
        offset = offset_top;
        if (manual_spacer == null) {
          if (el_float === "left" || el_float === "right") {
            elm.insertAfter(spacer);
          }
          spacer.detach();
        }
        css = {
          position: "",
          width: "",
          top: ""
        };
        elm.css(css).removeClass(sticky_class).trigger("sticky_kit:unstick");
      }
      if (inner_scrolling) {
        win_height = win.height();
        if (height + offset_top > win_height) {
          if (!bottomed) {
            offset -= delta;
            offset = Math.max(win_height - height, offset);
            offset = Math.min(offset_top, offset);
            if (fixed) {
              elm.css({
                top: offset + "px"
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (scroll > top) {
        fixed = true;
        css = {
          position: "fixed",
          top: offset
        };
        css.width = elm.css("box-sizing") === "border-box" ? elm.outerWidth() + "px" : elm.width() + "px";
        elm.css(css).addClass(sticky_class);
        if (manual_spacer == null) {
          elm.after(spacer);
          if (el_float === "left" || el_float === "right") {
            spacer.append(elm);
          }
        }
        elm.trigger("sticky_kit:stick");
      }
    }
    if (fixed && enable_bottoming) {
      if (will_bottom == null) {
        will_bottom = scroll + height + offset > parent_height + parent_top;
      }
      if (!bottomed && will_bottom) {
        bottomed = true;
        if (parent.css("position") === "static") {
          parent.css({
            position: "relative"
          });
        }
        return elm.css({
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: padding_bottom,
          top: "auto"
        }).trigger("sticky_kit:bottom");
      }
    }
  };
  recalc_and_tick = function() {
    recalc();
    return tick();
  };
  detach = function() {
    detached = true;
    win.off("touchmove", tick);
    win.off("scroll", tick);
    win.off("resize", recalc_and_tick);
    $(document.body).off("sticky_kit:recalc", recalc_and_tick);
    elm.off("sticky_kit:detach", detach);
    elm.removeData("sticky_kit");
    elm.css({
      position: "",
      bottom: "",
      top: "",
      width: ""
    });
    parent.position("position", "");
    if (fixed) {
      if (manual_spacer == null) {
        if (el_float === "left" || el_float === "right") {
          elm.insertAfter(spacer);
        }
        spacer.remove();
      }
      return elm.removeClass(sticky_class);
    }
  };
  win.on("touchmove", tick);
  win.on("scroll", tick);
  win.on("resize", recalc_and_tick);
  $(document.body).on("sticky_kit:recalc", recalc_and_tick);
  elm.on("sticky_kit:detach", detach);
  return setTimeout(tick, 0);
};
for (i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
  elm = this[i];
  fn($(elm));
}
    return this;
  };

}).call(this);
```

Many thanks,

Scott

Comment: please show the relevant code

Comment: Not sure what code to show. Its just a standard woocommerce select box.

Comment: but since you are not getting the expected result there must be something wrong in that code, do you agree? It could be related to the css maybe. This way we cannot guess what is going on

Comment: Ok thanks. ive figured out whats causing it but still not sure how to fix it. Ive modified my original post.

Comment: I worked it out. Thanks :)